# Override conroller/module for create product

Tags: mysql, model-view-controller, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I only want to know which file(s) in prestashop 1.6 is for create the product in backend (to save in database)?

I want to limit to create products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `controllers/admin/AdminProductsController.php` and `classes/Product.php`.

But you should learn and use `overriding` if you don't want to ruin your Prestashop. Start here: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors.

Comment: Do you know the exact line(s)?

Comment: Exact lines depends on your exact code you want to implement.

Comment: Like i said: I want to limit to create products! I think i've to `COUNT` the products in database first. Example: `If` there no 500 products in the database you can create a new product, `else` (there are 500 products) you don't create a new product.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not a place to get a code from developers for free :) First try to write your code by yourself, try hundred times and then if you are totally stucked – ask for a help in finding what is wrong in your code.

Comment: Lol if i knew the exact lines i would test it by myself!